# Replace string in list with python

Tags: python, string, list, replace

trying to replace all elements named 'number' to 'numbr' in the data list but doesn't get it working.

Edit: So each key number should be renamed to numbr. Values stay as they are.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

```
data = [{'address': {
                  'city': 'city A',
                  'company_name': 'company A'},
        'amount': 998,
        'items': [{'description': 'desc A1','number': 'number A1'}],
        'number': 'number of A',
        'service_date': {
                      'type': 'DEFAULT',
                      'date': '2015-11-18'},
        'vat_option': 123},
        {'address': {
                  'city': 'city B',
                  'company_name': 'company B'},
       'amount': 222,
       'items': [{'description': 'desc B1','number': 'number B1'},
                 {'description': 'desc B2','number': 'number B2'}],
       'number': 'number of B',
       'service_date': {
                     'type': 'DEFAULT',
                     'date': '2015-11-18'},
       'vat_option': 456}
       ]

def replace(l, X, Y):
  for i,v in enumerate(l):
      if v == X:
         l.pop(i)
         l.insert(i, Y)

replace(data, 'number', 'numbr')

print data
```

Comment: it should rename only keys? Post the expected result

Comment: This is the result - as you can see, no change:

[{'vat_option': 123, 'items': [{'description': 'desc A1', 'number': 'number A1'}], 'number': 'number of A', 'amount': 998, 'address': {'city': 'city A', 'company_name': 'company A'}, 'service_date': {'date': '2015-11-18', 'type': 'DEFAULT'}}, {'vat_option': 456, 'items': [{'description': 'desc B1', 'number': 'number B1'}, {'description': 'desc B2', 'number': 'number B2'}], 'number': 'number of B', 'amount': 222, 'address': {'city': 'city B', 'company_name': 'company B'}, 'service_date': {'date': '2015-11-18', 'type': 'DEFAULT'}}]

Comment: I've asked for the **expected** result, not the actual

Comment: Sorry. Expected result is: [{'vat_option': 123, 'items': [{'description': 'desc A1', 'numbr': 'number A1'}], 'numbr': 'number of A', 'amount': 998, 'address': {'city': 'city A', 'company_name': 'company A'}, 'service_date': {'date': '2015-11-18', 'type': 'DEFAULT'}}, {'vat_option': 456, 'items': [{'description': 'desc B1', 'numbr': 'number B1'}, {'description': 'desc B2', 'numbr': 'number B2'}], 'numbr': 'number of B', 'amount': 222, 'address': {'city': 'city B', 'company_name': 'company B'}, 'service_date': {'date': '2015-11-18', 'type': 'DEFAULT'}}]

Comment: So each key number -> numbr. Values stay as they are.

Comment: please move that into your question

Answer (score 1):

The following is a recursive replace implementation that replaces `p1` by `p2` in any string it encounters in the `s` object, recursing through lists, sets, tuples, dicts (both keys and values):

```
def nested_replace(s, p1, p2):
  if isinstance(s, basestring):  # Python2
  # if isinstance(s, (str, bytes)):  # Python3
    return s.replace(p1, p2)
  if isinstance(s, (list, tuple, set)):
    return type(s)(nested_replace(x, p1, p2) for x in s)
  if isinstance(s, dict):
    return {nested_replace(k, p1, p2): nested_replace(v, p1, p2) for k, v in s.items()}
  return s

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(nested_replace(data, 'number', 'numbr'))
[{'address': {'city': 'city A', 'company_name': 'company A'},
  'amount': 998,
  'items': [{'description': 'desc A1', 'numbr': 'numbr A1'}],
  'numbr': 'numbr of A',
  'service_date': {'date': '2015-11-18', 'type': 'DEFAULT'},
  'vat_option': 123},
 {'address': {'city': 'city B', 'company_name': 'company B'},
  'amount': 222,
  'items': [{'description': 'desc B1', 'numbr': 'numbr B1'},
            {'description': 'desc B2', 'numbr': 'numbr B2'}],
  'numbr': 'numbr of B',
  'service_date': {'date': '2015-11-18', 'type': 'DEFAULT'},
  'vat_option': 456}]
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That's a good start because it works fine! Awesome :)
Is there a chance to only replace the keys? Current result is: 'numbr': 'numbr of B',
it would be better to have it like: 'numbr': 'number of B',

Comment: Sure, remove the block dealing with lists and stuff. And in the dict block, replace `nested_replace(v, p1, p2)` by a simple `v`. You will lose the keys of nested dicts though...

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again - can you please take a look here? I think I got you wrong, because replacing is not working :(
def nested_replace(s, p1, p2):
  if isinstance(s, basestring):  # Python2
    return s.replace(p1, p2)
#  if isinstance(s, (list, tuple, set)):
#    return type(s)(nested_replace(x, p1, p2) for x in s)
  if isinstance(s, dict):
    return {nested_replace(k, p1, p2): v for k, v in s.items()}
  return s

Answer (score 0):

eval function is anti pattern, but I think eval is best solution here

```
data1 = eval(repr(data).replace('number', 'numbr'))
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! Thats a smart, small solution :D But I'd indeed like to replace only the key, value can stay as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replace both keys and values this will work.

```
from json import dumps, loads

    data = [{'address': {
                  'city': 'city A',
                  'company_name': 'company A'},
        'amount': 998,
        'items': [{'description': 'desc A1','number': 'number A1'}],
        'number': 'number of A',
        'service_date': {
                      'type': 'DEFAULT',
                      'date': '2015-11-18'},
        'vat_option': 123},
        {'address': {
                  'city': 'city B',
                  'company_name': 'company B'},
       'amount': 222,
       'items': [{'description': 'desc B1','number': 'number B1'},
                 {'description': 'desc B2','number': 'number B2'}],
       'number': 'number of B',
       'service_date': {
                     'type': 'DEFAULT',
                     'date': '2015-11-18'},
       'vat_option': 456}
       ]

data_string = dumps(data)
data = loads(data_string.replace('number', 'numbr')
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! Thats a smart, small solution :D But I'd indeed like to replace only the key, value can stay as is.